# Windows Task Scheduler vs. Windows Service with Advanced Python Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have a Python middleware application which polls a site for content, and then writes/updates a JSON file for a client-side web application.

I've investigated several ways for hosting this Python application on a Windows Server 2003 machine. I've set up the application to run every minute under the Windows Task Schedule, and have also looked at installing the application as a Windows Service (via NSSM).

Ideally, I'd like the application run continuously as an NSSM-managed Windows Service, with an internal task scheduler function to poll the various required sites every X seconds.

Would this be an acceptable solution? Or should I remove all polling components of the Python application, and use Windows Task Scheduling as the polling mechanism?

Comment: If you've already got the internal task scheduler in place, there's no obvious reason why you shouldn't do it that way.  No point in making unnecessary work for yourself.

Comment: If there are no obvious reasons against this method, I'll implement it for the time being and monitor the performance/stability. Thanks for commenting @HarryJohnston.